# Rails on production server with MySQL2 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am unable to do anything such as `rake db:create` on my production environment.

I've run `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` and `gem install mysql2` but both have been already install so I don't understand why I'm getting below error message:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:29:in `spec'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:101:in `create_database'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `each'
/var/www/tools/vendor/cache/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:62:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

What would be causing this issue?

Below is my `database.yml` file in `config` folder. When I change `production` into `sqlite3` it works:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: tools
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

Comment: Do you have gem 'mysql2' in your Gemfile ?

Comment: Yes I do have `gem 'mysql2'`

Comment: Ok then, try giving all permissions (777) to your `Gemfile.lock` and then restart the server

Comment: Delete Gemfile.lock. Run bundle install. Try rake.

Comment: I tried deleting Gemfile.lock and it came with error saying I need to recreate and upload from elsewhere

Comment: Removing `Gemfile.lock` is usually not recommended. Instead you should try running `bundle update mysql2`. That will update only that part in your `Gemfile.lock`.